# "New badge" popup contains link to wrong question

Tags: bug, design, badges

I decided to start a small bounty on a [well-worded question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38425515/2948765) (titled *Compute the maximum number of runs possible for a given length string* at the time of writing) which did not receive any answers until then and just awarded it. I spotted a minor bug after receiving the "Altruist" badge, the popup contains an incorrect link:

[image: image of popup]

[The linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8/how-can-i-convert-visual-j-code-to-c) (*How can I convert Visual J# code to C#?*) does not exist (which is no surprise looking at the URL) and I don't think I ever read it before.

The page about my Altruist badges contains the correct link:

[image: correct link on badge page]

Comment: It does exist, but it was deleted nearly two years ago.